# Bootstrap datetimepicker zone issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker installed on my website, which is this plugin: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

The problem I experience is that whenever a user has a different timezone, the time in the datetimepicker changes aswell. (The value is coming from the database and is a solid date)

So for example, my timezone it does:

[image]

Whenever I change my timezone, it reverts to this:

[image]

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one timezone default. Either in 'connect.php' or in 'head.php'. Fix it, wherever you feel suitable.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
```

Now, According to Bangkok, all user's time will get set.  Fix this code in that page, which is included in each and every page. That's the reason i prefer it to be in 'connect.php' or 'header.php'.